# Two columns layout with left column "over" right column effect

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to imitate this image:

[image]

([original image page](http://dribbble.com/shots/1121770-Location-Filters?list=following))

There's a shadow effect from the left column onto the right column, usually I use the faux columns method and put the background on the container but for this case the left column should be over the right column.

EDIT: I have now this base on your answer but the background on the sidebar doesn't stop at the container's height (it overflows to the bottom of the page).

```
#map-app {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 650px;

    width: 1200px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

    .sidebar {
        background-image: url('/data/images/map/v2/sidebar_separator.png');
        background-position: top right;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;

        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 350px;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    .content-container {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9998;
    }
}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

---

Any suggestions as of how I could achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a JSfiddle? Have you thought about using `box-shadow`?

Comment: Like stated in the question, I've tried 2 floats with a background on its container but that didn't fit since I needed the background/shadow to be on top of the second float. I thought of using some position:absolute magic but I thought that was very wrong practice. I don't have a JSFiddle yet but I can make one. I haven't tried box-shadow yet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To comment about the sass and compass making people afraid. I prefer using sass if a page or application I'm designing has very complex styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the left column will be positioned directly above the right, obviously use the z-index element and provide the left column with a shadow effect for the right border. This would allow you to fill the page entirely with the right column, and half with the left column, using z-index to set the left columns stack order above the right. I won't display any code for you if you won't show at least a snippet of what you have. Kind of pointless.

**Update: You would obviously have to use position: absolute; for both columns in order to achieve this effect you are aiming for, if you set it to relative the browser would not allow them to overlap.**

**Update: If you're looking to stretch both columns to the height of the browser, you'd obviously use the same container for both and set it's** `height: 100%;` **The problem with having a container, left column, and right column is, you can set the container to 100% height, but that just gives the content you put inside of it 100% height, doesn't mean the content will also be exactly 100% in size. What I would recommend doing is to change the container code to** `height: 100%; width: 100%;` **and only set one** `<div class="container"></div>`

**Code Update:**

```
.container {
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
}

.leftcolumn { // Guessing this would be your .sidebar
    overflow: hidden; // Option 1: Set the overflow to hidden.
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%; width: 50%; // Option 2: Set the height slightly lower. like 99%
    z-index: 9999; // Higher than right.
}

.rightcolumn {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    z-index: 9998; // Lower than left.
}
```

Comment: The reason I didn't added any code is I'm using compass/sass and I didn't wanted people to think "oh it's a compass question I don't know about it" and run away. It's a simple CSS question, and your answer seems to be what I was looking for so thanks :)

Comment: Using position: absolute, how would I keep that div as tall as its container? Height as to fit with the browser's height. Hum maybe using position: relative on the container?

Comment: It almost work! I updated the question with what I have, could you check if I did the right thing? thanks a lot for your help!